# Cannot debug script with trio_asyncio in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-trio

I have this (very simplified) program running with trio as base async library and with trio_asyncio library allowing me to call asyncio methods too:

```py
import asyncio
import trio
import trio_asyncio


async def async_main(*args):
  print('async_main start')
  async with trio_asyncio.open_loop() as loop:
    print('async_main before trio sleep')
    await trio.sleep(1)
    print('async_main before asyncio sleep')
    await trio_asyncio.aio_as_trio(asyncio.sleep)(2)
    print('async_main after sleeps')
  print('async_main stop')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('main start')
  trio.run(async_main)
  print('main stop')
```

It works well, if I run it from PyCharm:

```
main start
async_main start
async_main before trio sleep
async_main before asyncio sleep
async_main after sleeps
async_main stop
main stop
```

But if I run the same code from PyCharm in debug mode (menu Run / Debug), then it raises an exception:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 232.9559.58)
main start
async_main start
async_main before trio sleep
async_main before asyncio sleep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vaclav/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.2/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 12, in async_main
    await trio_asyncio.aio_as_trio(asyncio.sleep)(2)
  File "/home/vaclav/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/maybankwithoutselenium-RhkLw-zs-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/trio_asyncio/_adapter.py", line 54, in __call__
    return await self.loop.run_aio_coroutine(f)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/vaclav/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/maybankwithoutselenium-RhkLw-zs-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/trio_asyncio/_base.py", line 214, in run_aio_coroutine
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(coro, loop=self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/pycharm-community/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_asyncio_util/pydevd_nest_asyncio.py", line 156, in ensure_future
    return loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 436, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name, context=context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/pycharm-community/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_asyncio_util/pydevd_nest_asyncio.py", line 390, in task_new_init
    self._loop.call_soon(self, context=self._context)
  File "/home/vaclav/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/maybankwithoutselenium-RhkLw-zs-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/trio_asyncio/_base.py", line 312, in call_soon
    self._check_callback(callback, 'call_soon')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 776, in _check_callback
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: a callable object was expected by call_soon(), got <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<_call_defer() running at /home/vaclav/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/maybankwithoutselenium-RhkLw-zs-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/trio_asyncio/_adapter.py:16>>
python-BaseException
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_call_defer' was never awaited
Exception in default exception handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1797, in call_exception_handler
    self.default_exception_handler(context)
  File "/home/vaclav/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/maybankwithoutselenium-RhkLw-zs-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/trio_asyncio/_async.py", line 42, in default_exception_handler
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Task was destroyed but it is pending!

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The source code is copied from the [official `trio_asyncio` documentation](https://trio-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#trio_asyncio.open_loop).

I have two questions:

1. Why the code works well if it is run without debugging, and why it fails when it is run in debugger?
2. How I should modify this code to be able still call both - `trio` and `asyncio` methods and it will be possible to use debugger with such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me:

1. open `Actions` search window (press <kbd>shift</kbd> twice and switch to `Actions` tab)
2. type `Registry`, choose the `Registry...` item
3. switch off (deselect) the `python.debug.asyncio.repl` property

Thanks to Jetbrains support for help: [PY-65970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-65970)